# Are multiple alarms needed to set an alarm for different days?

Tags: android, sdk, alarmmanager

Just want to ask if, I need to set an alarm for different days, such as Tuesday and Friday , I would need different alarms. Would I also need different broadcast receivers and different pending intents as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need separate alarms. Repeating alarms only work on a fixed interval. No you won't necessarily need different broadcast receivers/pending intents unless you plan to handle those alarms differently.

Comment: Thanks kabuko - Thought having separate intents/pendingintents meant I could control the alarms better that was all.

Comment: That's fine if you have different functionality. I just wanted to note that it's not absolutely required. If your app always does something completely different on your Tuesday alarm as opposed to your Friday alarm, then by all means go ahead and setup different pending intents.

Comment: The app possibly will have the option to work differently on different days so because of this, should I have different intents,pendingitents and broadcastreceivers ?

Comment: Not enough detail for me to say for sure, but it sounds reasonable.